# How to access value from a Object using a dynamic key in Yaml

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml configuration as follows:

```
parameters:
  group: '$(group)'
  acl:
    certificateFile: AclCertificates.p12 
    provisioningProfileFile: AmericashDisProfile.mobileprovision
    keystore: 'acl.jks'
  sail:
    certificateFile: AclCertificates.p12 
    provisioningProfileFile: AmericashDisProfile.mobileprovision
    keystore: 'acl.jks'
steps:
- bash: |
    echo ${{ parameters[$(group)]['certificateFile'] }}
```

I want to access the object value using the dynamic key. Here `group: '$(group)'` is a dynamic value which is coming from another var file.
I have tried a way of access the object value like `${{ parameters[$(group)]['certificateFile'] }}` But its not working. I'm not able to figure out that how should i pass the parameter `group` in the `echo ${{ parameters[$(group)]['certificateFile'] }}` in order to get specific object's value.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a YAML pipeline A:

```
parameters:
- name: test
  type: object
  default:
    - name: Name1
      path: Path1
    - name: Name2
      path: Path2

variables:
   sth: ${{ join(';',parameters.test.*.name) }}
```

And then you can use YAML pipeline B to get the object value:

```
variables:
- template: azure-pipelines-2.yml  # Template reference

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'echo "${{variables.sth}}"'
```